# Power Query: Change source folder via drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, power-query

Before I start to explain - I am not providing any data or else, because I need an idea first, to see if it is possible (if it is easy).
Imagine you have one folder with X different subfolders inside, and every of them is filled with twenty text files, with same structure and length. What I normally do is uploading one folder Data > From File > From Folder in Excel and then doing certain transformations and saving it in an Excel file. That is what I am doing like X times for all ssubs.It is not super time consuming because I know how to change "Path" in Advanced editor, and with Refresh button is exceptionally smooth. BUT...
HOW TO: If I want to have for example one drop down list with those "subs" and every time when I change it on drop down with refresh button - my data set is in a minute refreshed. How to do that? Parameters or functions in PQ? That means I could avoid going into PQ editor or Changing source manually in M coding...
Any ideas or suggests?

Answer (score 0):

First I would tweak one of your existing query to start from the parent folder of all the "subs".  I would delete the rest.

I would build a table or named range with the list of "subs" - either of those can be read in a PQ Query. Then that "subs" query could be merged with the **Folder Path** column in your existing query to filter the list of folders (before the function call).